# how to check for internet issue and show error message

Tags: react-native

I want to show an error message if there is an internet issue  but how will I check whether the internet is down in react native, please let me know how can I implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library `@react-native-community/netinfo`. It has a listener, which will let you know when the internet disconnects.

```
const unsubscribe = NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
  console.log("Connection type", state.type);
  console.log("Is connected?", state.isConnected);
});

// Unsubscribe
unsubscribe();
```